# Second parameter not refreshing after the initial selection of the first parameter in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I did see a lot of other posts on similar questions but they did not help as my question is a little different.
I have 4 parameters in my report - 
Start Date (date - defaulted NULL), End Date (date - defaulted NULL), RecordID(text)(Listbox -defaulted to NULL), RecordID2(text)(Textbox)

User has two options to pull the report -

1) Enter a record ID in the "RecordID2" text box to pull the report

(OR) 2) Uncheck the NULL from the Start and End Date parameters which will create a drop down list in the RecordID parameter. User can select 1 RecordID from the drop down to pull the report.

For parameter "RecordID2", I have set the below default expression so that the Main Dataset always runs basesd on @RecordID2.

```
iif(Paramters!RecordID.Value ="", Nothing,Parameters!RecordID.Value)
```

I have also set the parameter Advanced properties to "Always Refresh".

Issue: Report runs fine for Option 1 and first run of Option 2. But, when I select a different value from the drop down, RecordID2 does not get updated.

For example: RecordID drop down has values ('1234','2345'). On selection of RecordID = '1234', RecordID2 textbox paramter updates to '1234' and the report runs fine. Later, when I select RecordID = '2345' RecordID2 textbox does not get updated to the new value - It still shows '1234'. The preview on changing the selection does look like its getting refreshed, but the textbox value does not get refreshed on this change.

Any ideas on how to fix this is?

Answer (score 3):

Two yrs later still the same issue, a trick I got after 2 days of testing is to set `default value` and `available value` both of the dependant param from a `dataset` and that dataset just returns processed value from first param.

Setting the `available value` will create a dropdown instead of text field for the 2nd param and that will change with the primary param.

See this example. By default `Period` is November and `test2` gets the correct value initially, but when you change it to October only the dropdown field `test1` changes but not the text field.

The only difference in the setup of these 2 params is that `test2` has no `available value` and just the `default value` (which is also same for both fields btw).

[image]

Comment: Setting the available params fixed this for me. Annoyingly, despite this being a problem for nigh on 4 years it's now also propagated to Power BI Paginated Reports too.

Comment: In Power BI Paginated Reports, if the user does not actually have to see the variable- set the dependent parameter visibility to "Internal" and this will dynamically update the dependent parameter as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in SSRS.  There are a number of ways around it, with a google for "SSRS cascading parameters not updating" returning many.

Such as http://www.bp-msbi.com/2011/04/ssrs-cascading-parameters-refresh-solved/

Comment: Appreciate your response. It is definitely a useful link. But, once I change my RecordID2 param to accept available values from the , it will not act as a textbox anymore. The whole purpose of giving 2 options to the user to pull the report is dead. I want  the second param to be updated to change of the first param.